# Nutch 1.4 integration with Solr 3.5 http.agent.name property

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, nutch

I have been trying to setup Nutch with Solr, but getting the following exception

Fetcher: No agents listed in 'http.agent.name' property.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fetcher: No agents listed in http.agent.name' property.

Answer (score 3):

As per the Nutch tutorial you should add an agent name in the following file:
    ./conf/nutch-default.xml
e.g.
    vi /opt/nutch/conf/nutch-default.xml
Change:
http.agent.name to:

```
    <name>http.agent.name</name>
    <value>nutch</value>
```

Also set values for http.agent.url and http.agent.email
for http.robots.agents - make sure the first entry matches your http.agent.name i.e.
        http.robots.agents
        nutch,*